# How to use Java reflection to create an instance of an @Autowired class

Tags: java, spring, reflection, autowired

I have a postgres database which stores (as a String) the relevant class to use dependent on the information coming in from the user.

e.g. user has input *Name*, the database has the value NameFinder() stored against this and the code needs to create an instance of NameFinder().

I was wondering if there was a way of using reflection to instantiate this class as an @Autowired component, and then call the relevant function.

I can't seem to find a guide that uses @Autowired classes so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is stored in the database? The FQN of the class?

Comment: @Hawk right now it's literally just the class name, but as it's a database it's easily configurable. I am willing to store anything in there to get this to work

Comment: how about writing code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For autowiring to work you need the class which uses @Autowired to be a @Component (or a child like @Service ...). https://www.baeldung.com/spring-autowire

For Spring to know what to inject, you need to define a @Bean in your Configuration
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean

As for the reflective instantiation in the bean:

```
@Bean
public Name getName(Database db) {
    String nameFqn = db.getConfigTable().getNameFQN();
    return (Name) Class.forName(nameFqn).getConstructor().newInstance();
}
```

Note this uses a no-arg public constructor. FQN means fully-qualified name, i.e. `com.some.pkg.NameFinder`
assuming:

```
package com.some.pkg;

class NameFinder implements Name {
    public NameFinder(){}
}
```

---

I feel like a Spring Bean should be configurable also directly from a FQN without using reflection but I don't know how. Try reading up on a BeanFactory or something similar. Usually reflection is to be avoided.

Comment: Thank you for the help. This doesn't seem to work for me though, as the code `Class.forName(nameFqn).getConstructor().newInstance();` returns an object of type capture#2-of ?

Comment: Looks like you forgot to cast the new `Object` to a `Name`

Comment: sorry I haven't had time to test it properly yet, I will as soon as I do